# Case insensitive queries using mongodb and javascript

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have the following mongodb code that works in returning a group name (regardless of case)

```
db.getCollection('groups').findOne({
      name: { $regex: /group1/i },
    });
```

However, i am trying to put this into my javascript app and i can't seem to get it to work with a variable storing the group name instead.

```
code = "group1";
const group: any = await this.groupModel.findOne({
  name: { $regex: /code/i },
});
```

Do i need special quotes around the code variable? Or does it need to be a different type or something?

Comment: You can use `new RegExp(code,"i")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, i had to change the regex line to this:

```
name: { $regex: code, $options: "i" },
```